# SSL verification error in program written in python

Tags: python, ssl, odoo

I have a python script that uses makes requests to odoo server using xmlrpc. The script runs fine but when I compile with pyinstaller and run on a windows server, I get this error.

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not
valid for 'xxx.dev.odoo.com'. (_ssl.c:992)
```

Research led me to download and install root certificates from [here](https://www.entrust.com/resources/certificate-solutions/tools/root-certificate-downloads). There seems to be no problem with ssl certificates when browsing with a normal browser. I also tried disabling with

```
common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy("%s/xmlrpc/2/common" % URL, \
    context=ssl._create_unverified_context()
    )
```

The date on the server also seems to be fine but Im still getting the error. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Okay. One of the things I tried worked. The program which was supposed to be run by task scheduler wasn't run so I assumed the log yielded the same result. Completely unrelated. Someone close this please.